# Java Date Comparison

Tags: java

According to Java API `public boolean before(Date when)`

> true if and only if the instant of time represented by this Date
>   object is strictly earlier than the instant represented by when; false
>   otherwise.

Now I have to check if date input by user is greater than current date then only it will accept the input otherwise throw exception so i tried below

```
if(userInputDate.before(new Date())){
      throw new Exception("Some Message");
     }
```

But if both date are same then also it going to inside `if` statement .Do it mean it will calculate time and then check rather than comparing date? If yes how to resolve my issue ?

Can any one tell me how to add check for this?

Comment: what you have is equivalent to `if(userInputDate.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis())` in case that helps you understand. (Both values are independant of timezones, they are ms since 1970 in UTC)

Comment: When you use `Date.before(Date t)` method, it checks every date parameter, including milliseconds. If you have created the date using `new Date()` , it creates a new date using the current time (almost accurate to the millisecond) so the chances that both dates are equal is very unlikely. So, in your case I would sugget you using (as @zapl has said) - `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead.

Comment: I think it is because the `Date` class contains also the milliseconds. Then, if you compare `userInputDate` with a `new Date()`, it is strictly probable that the first will be before the second.

Comment: an extra condition of if `if(userInputDate.before(new Date()) && !userInputDate.equals(new Date())){.....    }`

Comment: perhaps u could change usage Date to JodaTime or Java1.8 new LocalDate/LocalDateTime classes?

Answer (score 1):

The method `before` in the class `Date` is comparing the millisecond between the dates, so it's not comparing just the day, it is comparing the instant of time.

You could create a method to check if the dates are not in the same day and the first date is before the second one

```
public static boolean isBeforeDate(Date date1, Date date2) {       
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    boolean areTheSameDay = fmt.format(date1).equals(fmt.format(date2));
    return !areTheSameDay && date1.before(date2);
}
```

If you can use the new time api In Java8 instead of the old `Date` class, you can use the class `LocalDate` and the method `compareTo`:

```
boolean isBefore = myLocalDate.compareTo(myOtherLocalDate) < 0
```

Comment: I am using Java7 .

Comment: Then the class `Date` doesn't have a method to do exactly what you need. You have to do some extra work to compare the days.

Answer (score 0):

All methods on `java.util.Date` that allow one to separate the time of day from the day of the year are deprecated. Therefore it is better to use `java.util.Calendar`. Additionally one should consider that there is typically one hour in each year that is in two days when summer time ends.

Here are two ways you can do it:

```
public static boolean isBeforeDay(Date date1, Date date2) {
    // convert date1 to noon on the same day
    Calendar day1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    day1.setTime(date1);
    day1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    day1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    day1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    day1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // convert date2 to noon on the same day
    Calendar day2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    day2.setTime(date2);
    day2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    day2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    day2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    day2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return day1.before(day2);
}


public static boolean isBeforeDay(Date date1, Date date2) {
    // get yyyymmdd value from date1
    Calendar day1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    day1.setTime(date1);
    int ymd1 = 10000*day1.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 100*day1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + day1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // get yyyymmdd value from date2
    Calendar day2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    day2.setTime(date2);
    int ymd2 = 10000*day2.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 100*day2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + day2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return ymd1 < ymd2;
}
```